# Assign labels based on given examples for a large dataset effectively

Tags: matlab, large-data

I have matrix X (100000 X 10) and vector Y (100000 X 1). X rows are categorical and assume values 1 to 5, and labels are categorical too (11 to 20);

The rows of X are repetitive and there are only ~25% of unique rows, I want Y to have statistical mode of all the labels for a particular unique row.

And then there comes another dataset P (90000 X 10),  I want to predict labels Q based on the previous exercise.

What I tried is finding unique rows of X using unique in MATLAB, and then assign statistical mode of each of these labels for the unique rows. For P, I can use ismember and carry out the same.

The issue is in the size of the dataset and it takes an 1.5-2 hours to complete the process. Is there a vectorize version possible in MATLAB?

Here is my code:

```
[X_unique,~,ic] = unique(X,'rows','stable');
labels=zeros(length(X_unique),1);
for i=1:length(X_unique)
    labels(i)=mode(Y(ic==i));
end

Q=zeros(length(P),1);
for j=1:length(X_unique)
    Q(all(repmat(X_unique(j,:),length(P),1)==P,2))=label(j);
end
```

Comment: please post the code that took 1.5-2 hours so we can optimize it and understand what you are doing.

Comment: Attached Code for optimization

Comment: Try [profiling](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) it.

Comment: I did, the second for loop takes about 55% of the time, while the first about 32%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to accelerate your first loop a great deal if you replace it entirely with:

```
labels = accumarray(ic, Y, [], @(y) mode(y));
```

The second loop can be accelerated by using `all(bsxfun(@eq, X_unique(i,:), P), 2)` inside `Q(...)`. This is a good vectorized approach assuming your arrays are not extremely large w.r.t. the available memory on your machine. In addition, to save more time, you could use the `unique` trick you did with `X` on `P`, run all the comparisons on a much smaller array:

```
[P_unique, ~, IC_P] = unique(P, 'rows', 'stable');
```

**EDIT:**
to compute `Q_unique` in the following way: <s>and then convert it back to the full array using:</s>

```
Q_unique = zeros(length(P_unique),1);
for i = 1:length(X_unique)
    Q_unique(all(bsxfun(@eq, X_unique(i,:), P_unique), 2)) = labels(i)
end
```

and convert back to `Q_full` to match the original `P` input:

```
Q_full = Q_unique(IC_P);
```

**END EDIT**

Finally, if memory is an issue, in addition to everything above, you might want you use a semi-vectorized approach inside your second loop:

```
for i = 1:length(X_unique)
    idx = true(length(P), 1);
    for j = 1:size(X_unique,2)
        idx = idx & (X_unique(i,j) == P(:,j));
    end
    Q(idx) = labels(i);
%    Q(all(bsxfun(@eq, X_unique(i,:), P), 2)) = labels(i);
end
```

This would take about `x3` longer compared with `bsxfun` but if memory is limited then you gotta pay with speed.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Depending on your version of Matlab, you could also use `containers.Map` to your advantage by mapping textual representations of the numeric sequences to the calculated `labels`. See example below.

```
% find unique members of X to work with a smaller array
[X_unique, ~, IC_X] = unique(X, 'rows', 'stable');
% compute labels
labels = accumarray(IC_X, Y, [], @(y) mode(y)); 
% convert X to cellstr -- textual representation of the number sequence
X_cellstr = cellstr(char(X_unique+48)); % 48 is ASCII for 0
% map each X to its label
X_map = containers.Map(X_cellstr, labels);
% find unique members of P to work with a smaller array
[P_unique, ~, IC_P] = unique(P, 'rows', 'stable');
% convert P to cellstr -- textual representation of the number sequence
P_cellstr = cellstr(char(P_unique+48)); % 48 is ASCII for 0
% --- EDIT --- avoiding error on missing keys in X_map --------------------
% find which P's exist in map
isInMapP = X_map.isKey(P_cellstr);
% pre-allocate Q_unique to the size of P_unique (can be any value you want)
Q_unique = nan(size(P_cellstr)); % NaN is safe to use since not a label
% find the labels for each P_unique that exists in X_map
Q_unique(isInMapP) = cell2mat(X_map.values(P_cellstr(isInMapP)));
% --- END EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------
% convert back to full Q array to match original P
Q_full = Q_unique(IC_P);
```

This takes about 15 seconds to run on my laptop. Most of which is consumed by computation of `mode`.

Comment: Can you explain the unique trick with P once? I am not sure what is IC in  :    Q_full = Q_unique(IC);

Comment: @GKS I edited the post and added an example. Additionally, I corrected a a typo I made: `IC` should have been `IC_P`. Hope it makes things clearer :).

Comment: That did help.. Now it takes half the time than previously.

Comment: That is incredibly fast. However, it returns an error for a feature it hasn't seen before. e.g., if P has a row which wasn't in X, then I expect Q to be filled it with something (zero, or previous value)

Comment: @GKS. Sorry about that. Since I didn't have your data, I had to make some assumptions. I edited the code to include missing key detection and replacement with `NaN` value. it can obviously be replaced by anything else. Hope it furthers things along for you. Cheers.